# Obter o nome da cor a partir do valor HEX

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

Eu estou tentando fazer um aplicativo Android que pode capturar as cores, mas eu só descobri como posso obter o valor HEX, mas eu realmente preciso do nome da cor! por favor preciso de uma alternativa que mostre o nome das cores

Abaixo está todo o código, mas onde diz

```
public static String makeHexString(int value) {
    return "#" + Integer.toHexString(value).substring(2);}
```

esta linha aqui, `Integer.toHexString`, como posso fazer isso para obter o nome da cor em vez do valor hexadecimal?

```
public class ColorItem implements Parcelable {

    protected final long mId;

    protected int mColor;

    protected String mName;

    protected final long mCreationTime;

    protected transient String mHexString;

    protected transient String mRgbString;

    protected transient String mHsvString;

    public ColorItem(long id, int color) {
        mId = id;
        mColor = color;
        mCreationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private ColorItem(Parcel in) {
        this.mId = in.readLong();
        this.mColor = in.readInt();
        this.mCreationTime = in.readLong();
        this.mName = in.readString();
    }

    public ColorItem(int color) {
        mId = mCreationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mColor = color;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return mColor;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        if (mColor != color) {
            mColor = color;
            mHexString = makeHexString(mColor);
            mRgbString = makeRgbString(mColor);
            mHsvString = makeHsvString(mColor);
        }
    }

    public long getCreationTime() {
        return mCreationTime;
    }

    public String getHexString() {
        if (mHexString == null) {
            mHexString = makeHexString(mColor);
        }
        return mHexString;
    }

    public String getRgbString() {
        if (mRgbString == null) {
            mRgbString = makeRgbString(mColor);
        }
        return mRgbString;
    }

    public String getHsvString() {
        if (mHsvString == null) {
            mHsvString = makeHsvString(mColor);
        }
        return mHsvString;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public static String makeHexString(int value) {
        return "#" + Integer.toHexString(value).substring(2);
    }

    public static String makeRgbString(int value) {
        return "rgb(" + Color.red(value) + ", " + Color.green(value) + ", " + Color.blue(value) + ")";
    }

    public static String makeHsvString(int value) {
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(value, hsv);
        return "hsv(" + (int) hsv[0] + "°, " + (int) (hsv[1] * 100) + "%, " + (int) (hsv[2] * 100) + "%)";
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(this.mId);
        dest.writeInt(this.mColor);
        dest.writeLong(this.mCreationTime);
        dest.writeString(this.mName);
    }

    public static final Creator<ColorItem> CREATOR = new Creator<ColorItem>() {
        public ColorItem createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ColorItem(source);
        }

        public ColorItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ColorItem[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Acho que nem todos os valores possíveis de cor possuem nomes. Na verdade, acho que só um conjunto bem limitado possui. Achei [esta lista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) mas não sei se é algo "oficial" (no sentido de ter uma norma que define os nomes "corretos" de cada cor) - por isso, acho mais fácil fazer um mapeamento para as que tem nome, e para as demais, use o valor hexa mesmo. Mesmo assim será algo arbitrário, ex: no link que passei, ADD8E6 é "light blue", mas se mudar para ADD8E7, muitos (eu incluso) não conseguem perceber a diferença. Continua sendo light blue? Não sei

Comment: então e se eu fizer uma espécie de range entre valores? por favor preciso de uma alternativa que mostre o nome das cores!!

Comment: Acho que o mais fácil é criar um mapeamento mesmo (seja com um `java.util.Map`, ou via algum arquivo de configuração, etc), que define o nome para cada valor, vai ser algo criado "na mão", pois desconheço algo que faça isso automaticamente. E não creio que haja um nome "oficial" para todas as cores, então talvez o range de valores seja uma alternativa.

Comment: por exemplo [esta](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json) lista de nomes? pode me ajudar a implementar isso no meu programa?

Comment: Primeiro eu definiria melhor o escopo. Vc precisa do nome de **qualquer** valor de cor possível? (usando RGB, são mais de 16 milhões de valores possíveis, é inviável que cada um tenha o seu próprio nome). Ou você define ranges de cores que possuem o mesmo nome (e mesmo assim é um trabalhão), ou define os valores que tem nomes e os que não tem. Depois eu [usaria um map, por exemplo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) para mapear cada valor com seu respectivo nome.

Comment: como é que eu posso implementar aquela lista que eu mandei anteriormente?

Comment: Veja o tutorial (link do meu comentário anterior) sobre como usar Map. Depois use o código hexa como chave e o nome como valor. Eu começaria por aí

Comment: @hkotsubo eu fiz uma lista de nomes em XML com os seus codigos Hexadecimla, será possivel trabalhar com isso?

Comment: @hkotsubo peço desculpa mas não percebi nada disso do " The Map Interface"

Comment: http://www.guj.com.br/t/hashmap/107481